# Почему вторая функция $.ajax срабатывает раньше первой?

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend

И почему при $('body').html(html) рендерится текущая страница, без внесённых изменений (которые должен был сделать серв при сабмите). Рендерится как надо только при принудительном обновлении страницы

```js
function orderFromBasket() {
    let form = $('#order-from-basket');
    form.submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: new FormData(this),
            cache:false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(){
                alert('OK')
            }
        })
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.2:8000/catalog/basket/',
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('body').html(html);
            alert(html)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Ну, срабатывает раньше, потому что вызывается сразу же при `orderFromBasket()`, а первая только по событию `submit` и гарантированно после вызова `orderFromBasket`

Comment: А почему тогда рендерится незименённая сервером html-страница?

Comment: _А почему тогда рендерится незименённая сервером html-страница_ я ничего не понял((((

Comment: Потому что она рендерится ДО изменения.